# Consulta a 2 tablas en oracle 8

Tags: oracle

Encontré que en `Oracle 8i` no funciona el `INNER`, casi lo logré , funciona , solo me falta ayuda con solo un detalle :

La tabla cabeceras tiene los campos id (unico), subtotal, iva, total la tabla detalle tiene los campos id ( puede ser mas de 1 ya que son las filas de una venta ) , tipo ( es un código de impuesto que aplica solo a algunas ventas y aparece solo 1 vez por id ) , importe ( que es el valor del impuesto cuando tipo es = 15.

Ocurre que en el resultado de la consulta , en cada fila de a.total me devuelve el importe sumado tantas veces como filas tiene ese id en detalle. la idea es que solo me muestre los registros que tienen b.tipo=15 y que a.total no lo multiplique.

```
SELECT a.ID, SUM(a.SUBTOTAL)AS SubTotal,SUM(a.IVA)AS IVA,SUM(a.TOTAL)AS TOTAL,SUM(a.TOTAL-(a.SUBTOTAL+a.IVA)) AS DIF,SUM(b.IMPORTE) AS IMPUESTO
    FROM CABECERAS a, DETALLE b 
    WHERE a.FECHA_EMISION=TO_DATE('01/07/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')
        AND a.PUESTO=123  
        AND (a.NRO_SERIE >= 10500 AND a.NRO_SERIE <= 10550)
        AND a.ID=b.ID(+)
        AND b.TIPO=15
    GROUP BY ROLLUP (a.ID)
```

Link :   https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfvz5.jpg

Comment: Nos mostras que intentaste? a ver si todavia te ofrecemos lo mismo que ya intentaste.. porque un select de este select mas el nuevo campo (o un join)  no funciono?

Comment: Perdón por no publicar lo que intenté, pero estoy como perdido. Quise agregar la segunda tabla al from lo cual no me funcionó, luego tambien quise usar EXIST pero no le encontré la forma. Si puedes darme un ejemplo de como lo harías me serviría para aprender y hacer otras pruebas.

Comment: Es importante incluir siempre la definición de las tablas sobre las que consultas para saber bien qué intentas hacer. Ojalá como texto para poder replicar tu problema más fácil.

Comment: La edición que has hecho ha eliminado practicamente la pregunta. La idea de editarla no es eliminar la información anterior, sino _completar_ y mejorar la pregunta para que cualquiera pueda comprender todo el problema al leerla. Por favor, edítala de nuevo y dejala completa. Un saludo.

Comment: Si, claro que me he dado cuenta. En este caso puntual, debido a la version de la base de datos, y a que los que me colaboraron no notaron el dato de la version, hice pruebas que daban errores varios , y finalmente tuve que cambiar casi toda la consulta. Lo que necesito de la consulta no cambió , lo que solicité desde el principio es exactamente lo que pedi . En el intermedio logré casi resolver el problema, solo me queda un detalle puntual, que está explicado correctamente y para lo cual no he tenido aun ayuda alguna. gracias igual.

Comment: @look68 tene en cuenta que originalmente no especificaste la base de datos, con lo cual las respuestas eran basadas en esa pregunta. Esto que esta ahora, es una pregunta totalmente nueva. Deberias haber cerrado la otra, dandola por aceptada o en el peor de los casos poniendo una respuesta vos de cual era el problema y cual la solucion, y haber abierto una nueva pregunta. Ahora lo que tenemos en un embrollo de respuestas que no son a la pregunta que esta, comentarios desactualizados y una pregunta que cada vez se entiende menos.

Comment: Si ves el titulo del hilo, que no fue modificado, dice Oracle 8 . Fuera de ello no le suma a nadie discutir, yo cuando ayudo con visual o php , lo hago directamente, y si no se, dejo a otro que sepa, sencillo. Igual te agradezco la molestia.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente utiliza el query que ya tenes, y usalo para armar un nuevo query, que tenga como from el que sabes que funciona.

Si llamamos a tu query A, podrias hacer algo asi:

```
select A.*, B.importe
from (todo tu select va aca) A 
    left join DETALLES B 
        on a.id = b.id and b.tipo = 15
```

Con eso deberias poder agregar la columna que queres.

Comment: Despues de muchas pruebas encontre que INNER JOIN no funciona con mi version oracle 8i. Logré que casi funcionara , me falta un ajuste que no encuentro como solucionar.
La tabla CABECERAS tiene 1 solo registro por cada ID , la tabla detalles puede tener mas de 1 con el mismo ID , ya que es el detalle de unas ventas. Les copio mi consulta, el error es que el campo TOTAL me suma el mismo importe por la cantidad de filas que contenga un mismo ID ( x2 x3 x4 etc ) en la tabla DETALLE .. aunque por cada ID en DETALLE hay solo 1 fila con el CAMPO TIPO=15 ... Que hago mal ?

Comment: como??? inner join funciona en cualquier base de datos en cualquier version...

Comment: @look68 y no entiendo tu problema.. a ver si actualizas la pregunta con el detalle de los datos de entrada y salida como te gustaria que fueran...

Comment: ahi actualice mi problema, ya casi funciona, solo me falta resolver 1 detalle q espero se entienda

Comment: @look68 tenes razon.. no repare en la version de tu base de datos, y si, no tenes join. Los joins se escribe como un producto cartesiano donde se define la informacion en el where. Aclara eso en tu pregunta porque es un dato casi vital.

Comment: https://es.scribd.com/document/118638365/8i-Vs-9i-Oracle-Joins en ese link menciona las diferencias entre la sintaxis de distintas versiones

Comment: Reformé la consulta de acuerdo a ello. Podras echarme una mano con lo que no estoy logrando resolver ? gracias !

Comment: @look68 por tu descripcion entiendo menos. Ejemplos de datos de entrada, que sale en tu query actualmente, y que queres que salga. y trata de no cambiar radicalmente tu pregunta, si no todas las respuestas que dimos no sirven para nada.

Comment: si claro, la cambie por lo del INNER. Quiero que salgan las filas enunciadas en el SELECT , con el rollup sale 1 fila mas con la suma de cada columna, eso ya funciona. El problema es que si un ID de CABECERAS tiene mas de una fila en la tabla DETALLE, en  "SUM(a.TOTAL)AS TOTAL" me multiplica el valor del campo por cada fila que haya en DETALLE.
CABECERAS es la cabecera de una venta y su importe. DETALLE son las filas de ese comprobante de venta, puede ser 1 o varios, pero solo en algunos comprobantes , y solo 1 vez x comprobante , existe TIPO=15 que es un impuesto que necesito discriminar

Comment: @look68 Y es correcto lo que hace.. por eso mi ejemplo hace el join despues de hacer todas las cuentas...

Comment: justamente le estoy diciendo en el WHERE : AND b.TIPO=15 , para que me filtre solo esa fila , pero no lo hace.

Comment: en "SUM(a.TOTAL)AS TOTAL" le suma al valor de una fila la cantidad de ocurrencia en DETALLE

Comment: ahi subi un link : https://imgur.com/a/tM4DY3k  , es la salida con el problema en la columna TOTAL

Comment: @look68 toda la informacion debe ir en la pregunta. no todo el mundo puede abrir imagenes.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

Ejemplo rápido:

```
SELECT CABECERAS.ID, SUM(CABECERAS.SUBTOTAL)AS SubTotal,SUM(CABECERAS.IVA)AS IVA,SUM(CABECERAS.TOTAL) AS TOTAL, SUM(CABECERAS.TOTAL-(CABECERAS.SUBTOTAL+CABECERAS.IVA)) AS DIF, DETALLE.IMPORTE FROM CABECERAS INNER JOIN DETALLE ON CABECERAS.ID=DETALLE.ID WHERE CABECERAS.FECHA_EMISION=TO_DATE('01/07/2019','DD/MM/YYYY') AND PUESTO=205 AND DETALLE.TIPO=15 AND (CABECERAS.NRO_SERIE >= 10537 AND CABECERAS.NRO_SERIE <= 10599) GROUP BY ROLLUP (CABECERAS.ID)
```

Luego es cuestión de ir indicando las columnas que quieras sacar de cada una.
El INNER JOIN te saca toda la información que está en ambas tablas para un mismo ID.

Comment: Y en que lugar de la cadena debería situarlo ?

Comment: Y esto como deberia usarse en base a lo que tiene el usuario?

Comment: edito con un ejemplo más completo

Comment: Esto en oracle no funciona (y no andaria en ninguna base no ansi), ya que te daria el error de que el campo detalle.importe no pertenece a ninguna funcion de agrupacion ni forma parte del group by. Tene en cuenta que esto es oracle.

Answer (score 0):

No obtuve ayuda, en realidad si pero equivocada, igualmente casi pude resolverlo exceptuando algún detalle menor que postearé nuevamente. Copio x si a alguien tiene una duda similar ... y ... Oracle 8.

```
SELECT a.ID, SUM(a.SUBTOTAL)AS SubTotal,SUM(a.IVA)AS IVA,SUM(a.TOTAL)AS TOTAL,SUM(a.TOTAL-(a.SUBTOTAL+a.IVA)) AS DIF,SUM(b.IMPORTE) AS IMPUESTO
FROM CABECERAS a, DETALLE b 
WHERE a.FECHA_EMISION=TO_DATE('01/07/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')
AND a.PUESTO=123  
AND (a.NRO_SERIE >= 10500 AND a.NRO_SERIE <= 10550)
AND a.ID=b.ID(+)
AND b.TIPO=15
GROUP BY ROLLUP (a.ID)
```